# How to filter DataGridView using TextBoxes and list as DataSource using Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

I am aiming to filter the datagridview using the TextBoxes.

This is my current code.

**Form**

```
// Load the datagrid with Product Specifications
List<ProductSpecificationModel> productSpecificationsList = new List<ProductSpecificationModel>();
public void refreshData()
{
    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    productSpecificationsList = db.GetSpecifications();
    productSpecGrid.DataSource = productSpecificationsList;  
}
```

I fill the list from an external class:

**DataAccess**

```
public List<ProductSpecificationModel> GetSpecifications()
{
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
    {
        var output = conn.Query<ProductSpecificationModel>(@"
                SELECT
                    ID,
                    ProductCode,
                    ProductDescription
                FROM ProductSpecifications;").ToList();
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class ProductSpecificationModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product Code")]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product Description")]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }    
}
```

**How I tried filtering**

```
private void searchFunction()
{
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();
    if (filterCode.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        parts.Add("ProductCode like '%" + filterCode.Text + "%'");
    }
    if (filterDescription.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        parts.Add("ProductDescription like '%" + filterDescription.Text + "%'");
    }

    (productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataView).RowFilter = string.Join(" and ", parts);

}

private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchFunction();
}
```

**Error**

When I click `search` this shows up:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Application.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Try 2**

Using these answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26608951/12485722

Also have tried this:

```
// From this
(productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataView).RowFilter = string.Join(" and ", parts);

>>>>>

// To this
(productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Join(" and ", parts);
```

**And the error:**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Application.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You want to use your debugger to break on this exception to know where it is happening, and eventually add null check in your filter (if the problem is there) to avoid doing anything on null objects.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot `(productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataView).RowFilter = "ProductCode like '0001'";` this throws the same error...

Comment: Because you are casting to the wrong type. Your data source is a `List<ProductSpecificationModel>` not a `DataTable` nor a `DataView`. You need here to use `LINQ` to filter the list.

Comment: @dr.null Never heard of `LINQ` I'll have a look into.

Comment: @dr.null something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479387/12485722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are trying to cast the `DataSource` to the wrong types.

Here:

```cs
(productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataView)
```

and here:

```cs
(productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataTable)
```

So, if you declare a variable like:

```cs
var ds = (productSpecGrid.DataSource as DataView);
```

The `ds` yields `null` and trying to access a method or set a property of a `null` object throws the `System.NullReferenceException` exception.

The right type of the `.DataSource` is:

```cs
List<ProductSpecificationModel>
```

So the right cast is:

```cs
(productSpecGrid.DataSource as List<ProductSpecificationModel>)
```

---

For the filter part, and as you are using a `List<T>`, use `LINQ` to get a filtered list and reset the `.DataSource` property.

For example:

```cs
using System.Linq;

private List<ProductSpecificationModel> Filter(string productCode, string productDescription)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productCode) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productDescription))
        return productSpecificationsList
            .Where(x => x.ProductCode
            .IndexOf(productCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 && x.ProductDescription
            .IndexOf(productDescription, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            .ToList();
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productCode))
        return productSpecificationsList.Where(x => x.ProductCode
        .IndexOf(productCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productDescription))
        return productSpecificationsList.Where(x => x.ProductDescription
        .IndexOf(productDescription, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
    else
        return productSpecificationsList;
}
```

... and call it like:

```cs
productSpecGrid.DataSource = Filter(filterCode.Text, filterDescription.Text);
```

... and to set back the main list:

```cs
productSpecGrid.DataSource = productSpecificationsList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a much shorter way of filtering data.

Here is the code:

```
private void filterCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox searchTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    var filteredList = productSpecificationsList.Where(c => c.ProductCode.Contains(filterCode.Text)).ToList();

    productSpecGrid.DataSource = filteredList;
}
```